# JQuery Mobile sqlite search on button click

Tags: javascript, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I'm relatively new to jQuery and I'm trying to search a sqlite database that is generated when  my app is loaded. I know the search button click event is firing, but no results are being returned, I'm desperate to find out how to solve this as I'm working on this for a uni project. I've looked up help all over the place to try and find the answer but nothing I try seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$('#searchButton').on('click'), function () {
    alert('Search button pressed');

    db.transaction(queryDB, successCB, errorCB);

}
};
});
}

function queryDB(tx) {
    var gameTitle = $('#searchBox).val ();
    tx.executeSql("SELECT gameID, gameName, gameGenre FROM tblGameDetails WHERE (gameName LIKE ?);", ["%"+gameTitle+"%"], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function querySuccess(tx,results){
    $('#GameList').empty();
    $.each(results.rows.item(index) {
    var row = results.rows.item(index);
    $('#GameList').append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+row['gameName']+'</h3><pclass="ui-li-desc">'+row['gameGenre']+'</p></a></li>');
    });
    $('#GameList').listview();
}
```

Comment: `$('#searchButton').on('click', function () {` remove `)` after `click`,.

Comment: Thanks for that - I feel like an idiot now, I missed out a hash as well, Thanks.

Comment: you have other mistakes, check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vPFS3/

Comment: Thanks Omar, great help